# Working with compressed csv/xml files and PHP

Tags: php, xml, loops, compression, simplexml

I'm looking for some advice re fastest and most reliable way to work with large csv/xml data files - without the script timing out or failing to load the file on the first attempt.

I have the below script, which demonstrates (through Codeigniter, although framework irrelevant) how I load the file and execute insert/update scripts etc.

However, I've noticed when running the script manually that half of the time the script times out on the first attempt to run it, despite my inclusion of set_time_limit(0). Similarly, sometimes I receive error messages stating that my script fails to load the xml file altogether - however, if I rerun the script, it usually works on 2nd or 3rd attempt.

This is pointless if I am using cron jobs to ensure my website's content is kept up to date automatically. The file can range from having 11,000 - 30,000 rows at a time and I know that is a lot - but there must be a more reliable way of doing this...

Any advice?

```
public function home() {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $this->load->model('Update_model');
    $this->Update_model->update_in_stock();
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('compress.zlib://path/to/xml/compression/gzip/');
    foreach ($xml->merchant as $merchant)
    {
        $merchant_id   = (string) $merchant['id'];
        $merchant_name = (string) $merchant['name'];
        $data          = array(
            'merchant_id' => $merchant_id,
            'merchant_name' => $merchant_name
        );
        $this->load->model('Insert_model');
        $this->Insert_model->insert_merchants($data);
        foreach ($merchant->prod as $prod)
        {
            $aw_product_id = (string) $prod['id'];
            $in_stock      = (string) $prod['in_stock'];
            foreach ($prod->text as $text)
            {
                $product_name = (string) $text->name;
            }
            foreach ($prod->uri as $uri)
            {
                $aw_deep_link = (string) $uri->awTrack;
                $aw_image_url = (string) $uri->awImage;
            }
            foreach ($prod->price as $price)
            {
                $search_price = (string) $price->buynow;
                $rrp_price    = (string) $price->rrp;
            }
            foreach ($prod->cat as $cat)
            {
                $category_id   = (string) $cat->awCatId;
                $category_name = (string) $cat->awCat;
            }
            foreach ($prod->brand as $brand)
            {
                $brand_id   = (string) $brand->awBrandId;
                $brand_name = (string) $brand->brandName;
            }
            $data = array(
                'merchant_id' => $merchant_id,
                'merchant_name' => $merchant_name,
                'aw_product_id' => $aw_product_id,
                'in_stock' => $in_stock,
                'product_name' => $product_name,
                'aw_deep_link' => $aw_deep_link,
                'aw_image_url' => $aw_image_url,
                'search_price' => $search_price,
                'rrp_price' => $rrp_price,
                'category_id' => $category_id,
                'category_name' => $category_name,
                'brand_id' => $brand_id,
                'brand_name' => $brand_name
            );
            $this->Insert_model->insert_products($data);
        }
    }
    echo 'Update complete!';
}
```

Comment: If they're large xml files, and memory is an issue, you really should be using a pull-parser like XMLReader rather than SimpleXML which loads the entire file into memory

Comment: Are you calling this using an HTTP request? Have you tried running the script from the CLI context? See [Running via the CLI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html).